# Problem working on combinations

Tags: combinations

In how many ways can the letters of the word CAT be arranged to form three-letter words, if you are permitted to repeat a letter any number of times?

Comment: Listing all the possibilities in, say alphabetical order, and counting would be faster than posting the question here and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first letter can be chosen in 3 ways. Same for the second and third one.

So it's $3^3=27$.